# Changing project's Unity version of existing game

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a game where I have access to it's complete code via dnspy and I can make plugins and mods for it with no issues.

The game is written in assembly csharp and
the dll. (which I never had to touch) in c++.

It uses unity 2015 and runs on 3.5 framework.

Also, I can extract .assets from the game such as backgrounds or literally anything else and run re-textures using an unity bundle via a modloader.

I want to implement some features from Nvidia packages that are not available with unity 2015.

Would it be possible to port this project to unity 2020 or 2021 without too many issues?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no `Unity 2015` you probably mean `Unity 4/5` .. the version naming was changed between `Unity 5.6` and `Unity 2017.1`  ^^ about how to do it: You simply open the project in the newer Unity version. Will there be complications most probably yes! A lot changes in the API within 5-6 years of course

Comment: I managed to do it. Spent the whole night fixing errors.